# Draw communication network in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying for writing Latex code the following picture but I am not getting how to draw it. I have searched some related examples, but it's hard to accept them. Can someone help me?

[image]

I would be truly grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of similar diagrams on this site. In order to find candidates to build on, you can do a [visual search](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8521/194703). Anyway, here is one of the many ways to draw this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,box/.style={draw,inner sep=1ex,thin},semithick]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={box},row sep=1em](mat) {
|[label={[name=l2]below:{$x(A_2)$}}]|Decoder 1\\
|[label={[align=center,yshift=1ex,name=l3]below:{$\vdots$\\ $x(A_n)$}}]|Decoder 2\\
Decoder $n$\\
};
\node[above=1em of mat-1-1] (l1) {$x(A_1)$};
\node[left=3em of mat.west,box] (E){Encoder};
\draw (E.east) -- ++ (2em,0) coordinate (aux) node[midway,above]{$y$};
\draw[<-] (E.west) -- ++ (-6em,0) node[midway,above]{$x_1,\dots,x_n$};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3} {
    \draw[->] (l\X) -- (mat-\X-1);
    \draw[->] (mat-\X-1.east) -- ++ (2.5em,0) node[midway,above]{$x_{\X}$};
    \draw[->] (aux) |- (mat-\X-1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think it is fair to say that using `quotes` and `chains` won't make the code more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Schrödinger's neat solution I want to contribute a forest based approach to the discussion:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}

\tikzmath{
    \Len{l sep} = 2.1cm;
    \Len{fork sep} = \Len{l sep}/2;
    \Len{s sep} = 1cm;
    \Len{label sep} = 0.3cm;
}
\newcommand\Label[1]{%
    \draw [<-, >=Latex] (.north) to ++(0,\Len{label sep} pt) node[above, inner ysep=1pt]{$#1$};
}
\newcommand\EdgeLabelNode[1]{%
    node[midway, above]{$#1$}
}
\forestset{
    e-label/.style = {
        edge label={\EdgeLabelNode{#1}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        grow'=east,
        l sep=\Len{l sep},
        s sep=\Len{s sep},
        fork sep=\Len{fork sep},
        anchor=west,
        parent anchor=east,
        child anchor=west,
        forked edge',
        edge={->, semithick, >=Latex}
    },
    for nodewalk={
        *{2}{children}
    }{
        node options={draw, semithick, inner ysep=1em, inner xsep=2em}
    }
    [,
        [Encoder, for n=3{s=-2.6*\Len{s sep}}, e-label={x_1,\ldots, x_n}
            [Decoder 1,
                [,e-label={x_1}]
            ]{\Label{x\left(A_1\right)}}
            [Decoder 2,
                [,e-label={x_2}]
            ]{\Label{x\left(A_2\right)}}
            [Decoder 3
                [,e-label={x_n}]
            ]{
                \Label{x\left(A_n\right)}
                \draw[loosely dotted, thick] ($(.north)!0.6!(!p.south)$) -- ($(.north)!0.9!(!p.south)$);
            }
        ] { \path(.east) -- ++(\Len{fork sep} pt,0) \EdgeLabelNode{y};}
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Note

If somebody knows a more elegant solution to label the path between "Encoder" and "Decoder ..." i would be more than grateful.